# Change the border color in checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the border color when the radio button is clicked, but the problem is the number of buttons, the id cannot be predicted, can anyone help? this is the dirty code that I made,

html

```
<div id='box1' class='box'><input id='grijs' type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">1</div>
<div id='box2' class='box'><input id='sepia' type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">2</div>
<div id='box3' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">3</div>
```

javascript

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
    if($(this).attr("id") == "grijs"){   
        $('#box1').removeClass('box').addClass('selected');
      $('#box2').removeClass().addClass('box');
      $('#box3').removeClass().addClass('box');
    }
    else if($(this).attr("id") == "sepia"){
      $('#box2').removeClass('box').addClass('selected');
      $('#box1').removeClass().addClass('box');
      $('#box3').removeClass().addClass('box');
    }
    else if($(this).attr("id") == "normal"){
      $('#box3').removeClass('box').addClass('selected');
      $('#box1').removeClass().addClass('box');
      $('#box2').removeClass().addClass('box');
    }
});
```

css

```
.box {
  border :1px solid red;
  width:10%;
}

.selected {
  border :1px solid blue;
  width:10%;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/QWWwLZM

any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Looks like a case for `this`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put generic code where you don't need to identify the id of clicked radio button's parent div.
See below code where you can remove `selected` class from the div containing that class and add it to the clicked radio button's parent div.

```js
$(function(){
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('box');
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('box').addClass('selected');
});
});
```

```css
.box {
  border :1px solid red;
  width:10%;
}

.selected {
  border :1px solid blue;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' class='box'><input id='grijs' type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">1</div>
<div id='box2' class='box'><input id='sepia' type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">2</div>
<div id='box3' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">3</div>
```

**EDIT**: to make the solution more robust, you can add any class to identify the correct parent div and which does not get alter by script. Below script will ensure that you get the correct div always even when you alter the html structure.

I have added 'radioparent' css class to identify the parent div and use toggle class to make toggling between box and selected classes

```js
$(function(){
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
    $('.selected').toggleClass('selected box');
    $(this).closest('div.radioparent').toggleClass('selected box');
});
});
```

```css
.box {
  border :1px solid red;
  width:10%;
}

.selected {
  border :1px solid blue;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' class='radioparent box'><input id='grijs' type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">1</div>
<div id='box2' class='radioparent box'><input id='sepia' type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">2</div>
<div id='box3' class='radioparent box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">3</div>
```

Comment: code will be applied to other divs closest. should be an each function here for id starts_with `box`

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui, yes we can put that restriction to get the correct div but right now only input element is present under div and there is no nested elements so this should be fine as this will not put extra burden on jquery script. If OP want he can put any other class to identify the correct parent div. Thanks for the thought, appreciated it.

Comment: hmmm, added another answer, if it helps to OP or anyone else in future

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui, great, that will be helpful

Comment: how about when the border in a table? => https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP

Comment: Did not get your query clearly as it seems like your codepen is working and showing red border on selected radio row. Please provide the exact issue or ask new question with your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [id^=box] to toggle classes for all divs with radio buttons and then mark selected to current.

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
        // toggles classes for all divs containing radio buttons and id starts with `box`
        $('[id^=box]').addClass('box').removeClass('selected');
        // toggles classes of clicked radio button's parent div
        $(this).parent().removeClass('box').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  border :1px solid red;
  width:10%;
}

.selected {
  border :1px solid blue;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' class='box'><input id='grijs' type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">1</div>
<div id='box2' class='box'><input id='sepia' type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">2</div>
<div id='box3' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">3</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With simple logic : Remove box All Class and add "Box" Class ,then push "selected" class in right box

```js
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
        $('.selected').removeClass().addClass('box');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
```

```css
.box {
  border :1px solid red;
  width:10%;
}

.selected {
  border :1px solid blue;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' class='box'><input id='grijs' type="radio" name="color" value="grijs">1</div>
<div id='box2' class='box'><input id='sepia' type="radio" name="color" value="sepia">2</div>
<div id='box3' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">3</div>
<div id='box4' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">4</div>
<div id='box5' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">5</div>
<div id='box6' class='box'><input id='normal' type="radio" name="color" value="normal">6</div>
```

Comment: 2 problems, 1- what if there are multiple classes in complete code ? 2- what if there are other divs in page having `selected` class

Comment: What happens if other radio entries identify them as a star with id = "Box ..." and are not included in the selection. In this case your code $ ('[id ^ = box]' ) will not work ..... your question does not apply here, it depends on your needs. here we give the solution and the user will adapt with his need. if not my solution is a simple answer to comprondre.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, but I failed to use it into my code, here is the code pen https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP , I want to the border of table color is changed when the radio button is clicked