# Change the border color in table when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the border color in a table when the radio button is clicked.

I've tried using jQuery but the result is not what I expected.

here is my code:
https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP

javascript:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {    
    $('.box-tr-1').removeClass().addClass('box-tr-1-se');
    $(this).parent().addClass('box-tr-1');
});
```

css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-item {
    width: 90%;
}
.box-tr-1 {
    border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 4px solid #ddd;
}
.box-tr-2 {
    border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 4px solid #ddd;
}

.box-tr-3 {
    border-top: 4px solid #ddd;
}

.box-tr-1-se {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    border-top: 4px solid red;
}
.box-tr-2-se {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    border-right: 4px solid red;
}

.box-tr-3-se {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP

Please help me, any help will be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269254/change-the-border-color-in-checked-radio-button , maybe it could help. Also your question is a bit too vague. Please try to explain more about what you want your code to do because the Codepen already shows the borders changing colors when a radio button is clicked. What is your expected result?

Comment: These grey border should be red?

Comment: yes, something like this but its still buggy https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP

Comment: @Ervan How is it still buggy? Please explain, or there is nothing anyone who is trying to help you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is a little mess, but it should work for your purpose:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {   
  $('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('box-tr-1-se');
    $(this).removeClass('box-tr-2-se');
  })
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('box-tr-1-se');
    $(this).parent().parent().next().addClass('box-tr-2-se')          
  }
});

.box-tr-2-se {
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
 }
```

**EDIT:** Add/remove text color:

```
$('.table-item input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $('.table-item tr').each(function(){
    //Previous methods...
    $(this).find('.red').removeClass('red')
  })
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    //Previous methods...
    $(this).parent().next().children().eq(1).addClass('red');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude you saved my day, now one a question again, how to change the green text depends on the radio button when its clicked? https://codepen.io/ervannnn/pen/gOObrdP

Comment: When button is checked in which colour text should be displayed?

Comment: the green text (price), it should be red too when the button is clicked, can you help me?